# Can set php in file_get_content?

Tags: php, html

I would like to ask can i make the url in file_get_content() become changeable according to the port that user click? For example, if user click port2 will become

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://..port2.html');
```

while if user click port 3 will become

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://..port3.html');
```

i try to set the link as

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://..port<?=$mrtg_id?>.html');
```

but it shown error. Any suggestion?

Comment: 1. What's the error? 2.Where do you define $mrtg_id?

Comment: Perhaps you could. If only we knew what error you got. Also investigate double quoted strings for interpolation.

Comment: Do you have PHP short tags disabled those are the `<?= ?>` instead of the `<?php echo .. ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in more ways:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://..port".$mrtg_id.".html");
$html = file_get_contents("http://..port{$mrtg_id}.html");
$html = file_get_contents("http://..port{$mrtg_id}.html");
$html = file_get_contents('http://..port'.$mrtg_id.'.html');
```

Note the URL is enclosed with different characters (", ')

Check the manual for more informations:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this:

`$html = file_get_contents('http://..port<?=$mrtg_id?>.html');`

because the parameter is a string literal in single quotes and php will parse it as plain text, so what you are feeding into `file_get_contents()` is exactly this:

`http://..port<?=$mrtg_id?>.html`

Secondly, you do not want to use `<?= <value> ?>` inside a string context because this serves to echo out a variable as a string *from php*. It is a shorthand version of `<?php echo <value> ?>`, and you are trying to do this *from within a string* that is effectively being echoed out as the parameter string value.

So, what you need is to take advantage of double quotes, which allows php parsing of variables inside the string:

`$html = file_get_contents("http://..port{$mrtg_id}.html");`

See here for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to put PHP tag to assign a value here. Just simply replace with variable as below;

```
$mrtg_id= '47071544';
$content = file_get_contents('http://..port'.$mrtg_id.'.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use heredoc

```
     $html = file_get_contents(trim(<<<FILE
http://..port{$mrtg_id}.html
FILE;
));
```

Yes, its a bit overkill for this and you might have problems with line endings ( i added `trim()` ), but someone ( I wont call them out ) posted all the easy ones before I had a chance.

Oh, you could do it with implode too

```
$html = file_get_contents(implode(['http://..port',$mrtg_id,'.html']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$url = 'http://..port'.$mrtg_id.'.html';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

The code what you try:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://..port<?=$mrtg_id?>.html');
```

the string between `'` can't be parsered as a variable.